# Default number of availability zones for an AKS Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure-aks

I need to know how does AKS create its Kubernetes clusters from HA perspective. Specifically, I need to know what is the default number of availability zones when an Azure AKS clusters is created.

Answer (score 1):

Currently AKS does not support Availability Zones.

EDIT: this is no longer true.

Comment: Are there any design recommendations (documentation) to achieve high availability with AKS, for both master nodes and worker nodes?

Answer (score 0):

AKS already supports Availability Zones in many regions, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones.

It uses the zones you pass as `--zones` when you create the cluster. It will use only one (single AZ) by default if you don't set anything.